# Using string output from pytesseract to do a vlookup in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, vlookup, python-tesseract

I'm very new to Python, and I'm trying to make a simple image to song title to BPM program. My approach is using pytesseract to generate a string output; and then, using that string output, I wish to vlookup in a dataframe created by pandas. However, it always return zero value even though that song does exist in the data.

```
import PIL.ImageGrab
from PIL import ImageGrab
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
import pandas as pd

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

def getTitleImage(left, top, width, height):
    printscreen_pil = ImageGrab.grab((left, top, left + width, top + height))
    printscreen_numpy = np.array(printscreen_pil.getdata(), dtype='uint8') \
        .reshape((printscreen_pil.size[1], printscreen_pil.size[0], 3))
    return printscreen_numpy

# Printscreen:
titleImage = getTitleImage(x, y, w, h)

# pytesseract to string:
songTitle = pytesseract.image_to_string(titleImage)
print('Name of the song: ', songTitle)

# Importing the csv data via pandas.
songTable = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\leech\Desktop\songList.csv')

# A simple vlookup formula that return the BPM of the song by taking data from the same row.
bpmSong = songTable[songTable['Song Title'] == songTitle]['BPM'].sum()
print('The BPM of the song is: ', bpmSong)
```

**Output:**

```
Name of the song: Macarena

The BPM of the song is:  0
```

However, when I tried to forcefully provide the string to the songTitle variable, it works:

```
songTitle = 'Macarena'
print('Name of the song: ', songTitle)
songTable = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\leech\Desktop\songList.csv')
bpmSong = songTable[songTable['Song Title'] == songTitle]['BPM'].sum()
print('The BPM of the song is: ', bpmSong)
```

**Output:**

```
Name of the song: Macarena

The BPM of the song is:  103
```

I have checked the string generated from pytesseract: It has no extra space in the front or the back, totally identical to the forced string, but they still produce different results. What could be the problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
It is because the songTitle coming from:

```
songTitle = pytesseract.image_to_string(titleImage)
```

...is actually `'Macarena\n'` instead of `'Macarena'`.
They might look the same after print out, except the former will create a new line after it.
A great lesson learn for me.